# react with GraphQL Clients

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-boost

Using `React` with `GraphQL clients` like `Apollo Client` is a good idea? The same results i can achieve with `react` and new `Context API`.

Basically i can consume `GraphQL API`s using `axios` or any other libraries like this. And for state management i can use react's new `Context API`s which is really simple.

```
axios.get('localhost://4000?qraphql').then((res)=>{

//do something with the response.
})
```

Is there still any Advantages to go with `Apollo Client`. Why would I really go for `Apollo client` when i can achieve the same without it. It will help me to reduce my `bundle` size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apollo client provides a ton of features above and beyond simply fetching data from the server. What follows is a non-exhaustive list:

- Exposed loading, error and data state, so you don't have to create additional stateful components just to fetch data asynchronously
- A normalized caching layer that allows you to avoid making unnecessary repeat requests to your server
- Observable queries that allow your UI to update whenever any query or mutation changes a relevant part of the cache
- Powerful error handling tools through `apollo-link-error`
- Pagination support through `loadMore`
- Optimistic UI updates for mutations
- Support for Subscriptions through `apollo-link-ws`
- Integration with local state management through `apollo-link-state`
- Support for deferred queries through the `@defer` directive
- Server-side-rendering support
- Apollo Client Developer Tools chrome extension that includes built-in GraphiQL console, query watcher, mutation inspector and cache inspector.

See the extensive docs [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) for more details.

There are common patterns that result in having to write (and test) a bunch of boilerplate code, for example maintaining loading state so that your UI knows when a request is complete. Using Apollo, or any other similar client, eliminates the need to write all that boilerplate and provides a clean, well-tested API for you to work with. If you're working on a team, there's also something to be said for using a well-documented library that some of your team may already be familiar with, rather than having to learn some new API that was created just for a particular project.